# Remove Margin Top of The MuiInput right after a label

Tags: material-ui

I want to set the margin of the Input right after the label to 0 by default from createTheme, here is the CSS from MUI. Since it starts with *label*, I don't know which component I should edit. Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Override styles of `MuiInputLabel` like so:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& +.MuiInputBase-root": {
            marginTop: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit admiring-joji-h0g1l4]